# Variable that refers to a static class

Tags: actionscript-3

It's a really stupid thing to ask, but maybe someone could answer it.

How can I replace

```
public function Mainclass()
{
    Calculations.getDistance(5,9,4,2);
}
```

with something like this:

```
private var math:Class = Calculations;

public function Mainclass()
{
    math.getDistance(5,9,4,2);
}
```

":Class" doesn't work.

I'm not lazy (lying? :p), but I use the class more than 20 times, and it looks better if I replace al these long classnames.

Answer (score 0):

just tested in my project:

```
        private var fn:Function;
        /*...*/
        fn = PlayerMenu.makeBtn;
        var tf:TextField = new TextField();
        addChild(tf);
        fn(tf, new Point(500, 500), 'ololo');
```

works fine, however not very convinient cause FlashDevelop doesn't highlight arguments

Comment: You're using a reference to a function in the class PlayerMenu, I don't want to refer to a function, but to the class itself.
So not: `fn:Function`, but `class:Class`. But `:Class` doesn't work.

Comment: however, you can declare a variable of type 'Function` and store the reference to the desired static function there, not the exact thing you wanted, but imho it's a way to beautify that functions calls as well ;)